# How do I use pcl 1.7 with groovy?

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use the RSD-Feature from PCL, which is in their current trunk-version (must be 1.7, am I right?) with ROS groovy.
How can I compile the current pcl-trunk version for ros groovy? I found this github repo: github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl but I don't know how to use it.

I made the same thing half a year ago for ROS electric with a svn checkout from the svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/electric/perception_pcl_unstable/ and after that a "rosmake pcl" but the whole svn.pointclouds.org/ros/* does not exist anymore.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
kartoffelsalat

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62979/how-do-i-use-pcl-1.7-with-groovy?/) by [kartoffelsalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4921/kartoffelsalat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2013-05-17

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kartoffelsalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4921/kartoffelsalat/) on 2013-05-17**:
Sorry for not publishing complete links, but my karma isn't sufficient for this (why do I need karma for this action???)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-17**:
The askbot system has a minimum required karma for posting links to prevent spamming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did this a while back, here is what I did.

First you need to have the `pcl_ros` package in your workspace, or you need to install all of the debians which `pcl_ros` depends on. Since I am on a mac, I will fetch all of the dependencies and build them from source, so I will start like this:

**Note: the `/tmp` directory is cleared at reboot, you may want to pick a different directory**

```
cd /tmp
mkdir pcl_ws
cd pcl_ws
wstool init src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/pcl_ros
```

That downloaded `pcl_ros` and all of it's dependencies into the `src` folder, including `pcl-1.6` which is what is released with groovy. Lets remove that version of `pcl` so that we can replace it later:

```
rm -rf src/pcl
```

If you only want to rebuild `pcl` and `pcl_ros` from source then run `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pcl-ros` in order to get all of the dependencies you need and then setup a workspace with `pcl_ros` in it:

```
# Only do this if you did the apt-get and did not run wstool above
cd /tmp
mkdir pcl_ws
cd pcl_ws
mkdir src
cd src
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git
```

Either way, at this point you have the `/tmp/pcl_ws/src` folder now which contains at least `pcl_ros`. In the `src` folder you should clone the master of `pcl` (1.7):

```
cd /tmp/pcl_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git
```

Next you need to "ROS"-ify the `pcl` package. First you need the `package.xml` for `pcl`, we can get this from the released version (it hasn't changed from 1.6 to 1.7):

```
cd pcl
wget https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-release/release/pcl/1.6.0/package.xml
```

Next you will want to edit the `cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake` file to hard code the `USE_ROS` option to `ON`, here is a patch:

```
diff --git a/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake b/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake
index cf2e1e3..b426066 100644
--- a/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake
+++ b/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@ endmacro(get_ros_inc_path)
 set(ROS_DISTRO $ENV{ROS_DISTRO})

 if(ROS_DISTRO)
-    option(USE_ROS "Integrate with ROS rather than using native files" OFF)
+    option(USE_ROS "Integrate with ROS rather than using native files" ON)
     message(STATUS "Found ROS; USE_ROS is ${USE_ROS}; ROS-Distro: ${ROS_DISTRO}")
     if(USE_ROS)
         # Search for ROS
```

Now you can build your `pcl` workspace:

```
cd /tmp/pcl_ws
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash  # Only if you are using debians
catkin_make_isolated --install  # prefix with `./src/catkin/bin/` if not using debians
```

Now assuming you didn't run into any build errors (I didn't get any on my Mac just now), then you should have a folder at `/tmp/pcl_ws/install_isolated` which you can source to utilize `pcl` and `pcl_ros`:

```
source /tmp/pcl_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-05-20**:
I have successfully followed these instructions to get PCL trunk working with ROS Groovy.

**Comment by [kartoffelsalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4921/kartoffelsalat/) on 2013-05-30**:
Thanks for your quick reply, William! And shame on me for responding so late. I was successful, but it was not easy...Since PCL has also included an old version of libsvm, I ran into runtime error, I didn't expect at all.

**Comment by [kartoffelsalat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4921/kartoffelsalat/) on 2013-05-30**:
Nevertheless: The way you wrote how to use the compiled pcl-1.7 with ROS didn't worked for me. So I just copied the whole content of .../install_isolated into my /opt/ros/groovy and now its working! Thanks again!

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-15**:
The instructions don't work for me. pcl builds without a problem, however when it comes to plc_ros I got many linking problems with libpcl_ros_segmentation.dylib.

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-16**:
Linking CXX shared library /Users/artemlenskiy/ros/catkin_install/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_surface.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal>::performProcessing(pcl::PointCloudpcl::Normal&)", referenced from:
vtable fo

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-16**:
Any ideas how to solve this? I should mention that if I comment out all the lines related to ros_surface in CMakeLists.txt, plc_ros builds successfully.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-16**:
I don't know, I guess the trunk of PCL has a breaking change now. I would file a ticket on pcl_ros.

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-06-30**:
Hi I had an error here: [ 87%] Built target flann_s

CalledProcessError: Command '/tmp/pcl_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8' returned non-zero exit status 2
<== Failed to process package 'flann':
Command '/tmp/pcl_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8' returned non-zero exit status 2

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-06-30**:
any help?thanks in advance!

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-06-30**:
Hmm I did not do anything for this part of the patch:

diff --git a/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake b/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake
index cf2e1e3..b426066 100644
--- a/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake
+++ b/cmake/pcl_find_ros.cmake

Is there something to edit in this part?

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-30**:
It is hard to say without a full log, but try to turn off CUDA support in CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-07-01**:
Which CMakeLists.txt would that be?
is it the one at /tmp/pcl_ws/src/flann?

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-07-01**:
set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on ) in CMakeLists.txt the one in PCL. Regarding CUDA, I recently had troubles compiling FLANN with CUDA support.

**Comment by [sran](https://answers.ros.org/users/5349/sran/) on 2013-07-08**:
I have exact same problem as VicL and I can't find set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on) in CMakeLIsts.txt in pcl directory... Can anybody help with this? Thank you so much in advance

**Comment by [Seanny123](https://answers.ros.org/users/8436/seanny123/) on 2013-12-01**:
May I suggest an edit? Could you note at the beginning that you should not use the `/tmp` directory if you intend to recompile the source again later, since it will be deleted after you re-boot?

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-22**:
Is this still the preferred way to do this? There's no pcl_find_ros.cmake file in the pcl repo anymore so I can't follow these instructions.

**Comment by [vincentweisen](https://answers.ros.org/users/22039/vincentweisen/) on 2015-09-10**:
I found this error !!

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1202 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's also an unstable package [pcl17](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17) designed to enable using more recent pcl side by side with the released pcl. This may only work for fuerte though.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-17**:
I think this might be for ROS Fuerte, @MichaelKorn can you comment?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-05-18**:
Yes, it's for fuerte. I'm still using fuerte but I think I will have some time in the next two week and I will switch to groovy.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try
`git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b groovy-unstable-devel`

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-06-15**:
This one works. Just had to modify .//pcl/doc/tutorials/content/walkthrough.rst by changing pcl-1.6 to pcl-1.7.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-23**:
This no longer works. I get all kinds of linker errors when attempting to catkin_make_isolated this.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-23**:
I've gotten a little farther on this: if you checkout revision 528328f, it refers to a version of PCL from before USE_ROS was removed. This one builds. However, I don't know how to build my own project with it. I've overlayed my (dry) workspace on top of my new pcl workspace, but I have errors...

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-23**:
Oops, nevermind! Those were my own errors. So yes, looks like this builds if you check out branch groovy-unstable-devel, revision 528328f, place it into the src/ folder of a new catkin workspace, and run catkin_make_isolated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@William would be great to add your instructions to http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

Another simpler solution that I followed is to to replace PCL that comes to with groovy with this one
https://github.com/kalectro/pcl_groovy
it builds on Mac OSX 10.8 with out a problem. Although it's PCL 1.6.1.
Also I am not sure if PCL 1.6.1  has rsd features, probably not.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-10**:
This might better go on a PCL related wiki page, perhaps in tutorial form, I would welcome help in improving the wiki documentation here.

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2014-02-24**:
Hello @Artem an @William,

I did the " git clone https://github.com/kalectro/pcl_groovy " and it downloaded the package " pcl_groovy " but I dont know from now what should I do? there is no MAKE or something,

I am new in ROS so I appreciate that you help me...

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2014-02-24**:
This is outdated info. Did you try just following this instructions http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source and choosing desktop-full Install?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a more recent answer. This works on my Ubuntu 12.04 as of 08/2014. This is a more detailed version of [Michael Korn's answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/62979/how-do-i-use-pcl-17-with-groovy/?answer=64259#post-id-64259).

```
$ mkdir -p pcl_ws/src
$ cd pcl_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b groovy-unstable-devel
$ cd perception_pcl
$ git checkout 528328f
$ cd ..
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make_isolated    # this step takes awhile
```

**If you're trying to build a Catkin package:**

(I've not tested this; I have a rosbuild workspace.)

```
$ source pcl_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash
$ cd <your catkin groovy workspace>
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

**If you're trying to build a Rosbuild package:**

```
$ cd <your rosbuild groovy workspace>
$ vim .rosinstall
```

change this line:

```
- setup-file: {local-name: /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh}
```

to this:

```
- setup-file: {local-name: path/to/pcl_ws/devel_isolated/setup.sh}
```

Now,

```
$ source setup.bash
$ rosmake <your package that needs PCL 1.7>
```

**Voilà!**

Now, if you look for pcl_ros, it should show you the custom-built version:

```
$ rospack find pcl_ros
/path/to/pcl_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros
```

(FYI, what you have done is built your own version of the pcl_ros package and PCL and overlayed them on top of your existing ROS Groovy installation. The version of PCL you built is not quite the 1.7.0 release, but it hopefully has whatever you want to use. For more on overlaying workspaces see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin).)

---

Originally posted by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) with karma: 205 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has been tested successfully:)

$ mkdir -p pcl_ws/src
$ cd pcl_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b groovy-unstable-devel
$ cd perception_pcl
$ git checkout 528328f
$ cd ..
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make_isolated
[above step takes awhile]
$ cd
$ vim .rosinstall
change this line:

```
setup-file: {local-name: /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh} to this (edit below path to point to your new workspace):
setup-file: {local-name: ../pcl_ws/devel_isolated/setup.sh} $ source setup.bash [if you echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH you should now see both workspaces]
```

$ rosmake file

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1